# Difficulty with projectile's tracking code

Tags: c#, tracking, trigonometry

I wrote some code for a projectile class in my game that makes it track targets if it can:

```
            if (_target != null && !_target.IsDead)
            {
                Vector2 currentDirectionVector = this.Body.LinearVelocity;
                currentDirectionVector.Normalize();
                float currentDirection = (float)Math.Atan2(currentDirectionVector.Y, currentDirectionVector.X);
                Vector2 targetDirectionVector = this._target.Position - this.Position;
                targetDirectionVector.Normalize();
                float targetDirection = (float)Math.Atan2(targetDirectionVector.Y, targetDirectionVector.X);
                float targetDirectionDelta = targetDirection - currentDirection;
                if (MathFunctions.IsInRange(targetDirectionDelta, -(Info.TrackingRate * deltaTime), Info.TrackingRate * deltaTime))
                {
                    Body.LinearVelocity = targetDirectionVector * Info.FiringVelocity;
                }
                else if (targetDirectionDelta > 0)
                {
                    float newDirection = currentDirection + Info.TrackingRate * deltaTime;
                    Body.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(
                        (float)Math.Cos(newDirection),
                        (float)Math.Sin(newDirection)) * Info.FiringVelocity;
                }
                else if (targetDirectionDelta < 0)
                {
                    float newDirection = currentDirection - Info.TrackingRate * deltaTime;
                    Body.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(
                        (float)Math.Cos(newDirection),
                        (float)Math.Sin(newDirection)) * Info.FiringVelocity;
                }
            }
```

This works sometimes, but depending on the relative angle to the target projectiles turn away from the target instead. I'm stumped; can someone point out the flaw in my code?

Update: thinking about it and trying stuff has led me to the conclusion that it has something to do with when the direction (being in radians) is below 0 and the current projectile angle is above 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `targetDirectionDelta` is not always the shortest direction to the target. If the absolute value of `targetDirectionDelta` is greater than PI radians, it will appear the projectile is turning away from the target. Turning in the other direction is shorter and expected.

**Example:**

```
currentDirection = 2
targetDirection = -2
```

The projectile can turn -4 radians (in the negative direction), or 2*(PI-2) radians (about 2.2 radians) (in the positive direction).

For this case, your code always calculates the longer direction, but you are expecting the projectile to turn towards the shorter direction:

`targetDirectionDelta = targetDirection - currentDirection`

Comment: Yes, somehow i forgot to say this. I solved it by adding in a check to see if `targetDirectionDelta` is above pi or below -pi first, which tells me that i would take the long way otherwise.